# Intellij 2019 2.3 Exception in plugin Andriod Support

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

I need help, when on the design tab in activity_main.xml, clicking on a widget causes the error. Also the attributes panel for the widgets are blank no matter which i click and sometimes shows loading but never appears.Tried switching to the "all attributes view" but still can change any of the attributes.
Already tried to deactivate the instant run, invalidate caches, slightly older version of IntelliJ, deleting and re-downloading IntelliJ and "clean project"

the error msg:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsComboBoxUI
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.editors.EnumEditor$CustomComboBox.setUI(EnumEditor.java:470)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.updateUI(JComboBox.java:277)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.init(JComboBox.java:236)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.<init>(JComboBox.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.ComboBoxWithWidePopup.<init>(ComboBoxWithWidePopup.java:15)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.ComboBox.<init>(ComboBox.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.editors.EnumEditor$CustomComboBox.<init>(EnumEditor.java:440)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.NlEnumEditor.createForInspectorWithBrowseButton(NlEnumEditor.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider$IdInspectorComponent.<init>(IdInspectorProvider.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider.createCustomInspector(IdInspectorProvider.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider.createCustomInspector(IdInspectorProvider.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.inspector.InspectorProviders.createInspectorComponents(InspectorProviders.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.inspector.InspectorPanel.setComponent(InspectorPanel.java:260)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesPanel.setItems(NlPropertiesPanel.java:281)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.PropertiesManager.lambda$null$0(PropertiesManager.java:247)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:824)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:773)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:412)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:411)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.4] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@7355d4d1
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the issue with compatibility with 11 JDK that IDE uses to tun. Configure IDE to run under 1.8 JDK: can be downloaded from [bintray](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk) and set via JDK Switcher as per [Switch boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) steps or download IntelliJ IDEA with bundled 8 JBR from [Other IntelliJ IDEA Versions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html).